# Приложение вылетает при запросе к сети

Tags: java, android, сеть

Приложение содержит 1 `Activity`, в методе `onCreate` содержится следующий код:

```
    int c;
    URL myUrl = null;
    try {
        myUrl = new URL("http://www.pro-java.ru");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection myUrlCon = null;
    try {
        myUrlCon = myUrl.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long length = myUrlCon.getContentLength();

    String data = "";
    if(length != 0) {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = myUrlCon.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            while(((c = input.read()) != -1)) {
                data = data.concat(String.valueOf(c));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Манифест:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.tcptest">

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
          <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
      </application>

  </manifest>
```

Чем может быть вызвано вылетание?

Comment: Хрустальный шар говорит, что у вас вылетает исключение [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

Comment: @Андрей вынесите работу с сетью в отдельный поток, нельзя этого делать в UIThread.

Comment: Всем спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чем может быть вызвано вылетание?

Оно вызвано тем, что сетевые операции нельзя производить в UI-потоке. При работе с сетью в UI-потоке будет сгенерировано `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

В самом простейшем **учебном** случае можно воспользоваться `AsyncTask`, но **лучше использовать другие средства** для работы с интернетом, которые из коробки поддерживают работу в отличных от UI потоках, например [`OkHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Также можно воспользоваться чем-нибудь вроде `Rx`, или, например, `Robospice` или `Chronos`.

Comment: Robospice последние 2 года не развивался, не стоит его смотреть

Comment: @DeKaNszn, Она уже старая, да, но с задачами справляется.

Comment: да, но не каждый человек умеет самостоятельно накладывать патчи с фиксами из github issues